# Multiple tasks with same sudo_user in Ansible role?

Tags: dry, ansible

I have a bunch of tasks in a role that repeatedly use:

```
sudo: yes
sudo_user: my_user
```

Isn't there a way that I can set these attributes for multiple tasks, so it will be more DRY?

I know I can change the user in the playbook, but other tasks need user `root`, so I can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

In your inventory file you can have multiple groups, ie: root_access group or deploy_user group. So you define your hosts, say like this;

```
[web]
webby-1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.1
webby-2 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-192-168-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[foo:children]
web

[foo:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=foo
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/foo.pem

[bar:children]
web

[bar:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=bar
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/bar.pem
```

and then you can call them based on the inventory groups.

Comment: Yeah, but then you're still tied to 1 user for a complete playbook. I want to specify an alternative user for a couple of tasks inside a playbook, not all the tasks.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you're going to be retyping it, or running that role as a specific playbook in your list of playbooks to run. It can only be per playbook, not per role or task (as of this writing)